# Configuring iptables for ftp between windows 8 and a windows server: does rst clear nat?

Tags: windows-8, ftp, iptables, nat

The underlying problem is I can't upload a file via ftp from a windows 8 laptop to a windows server through my linux/iptables firewall (passive or active ftp, doesn't matter). Works with windows 7, linux, and when I remove the firewall.

I logged all of the packets to and from the server and the same pattern shows up every time it fails. Everything looks normal until I see an RST packet from the server to my laptop. It's from and to ports that have previously been set up and used. The packet is forwarded to the laptop. So far it looks fine. Then the server sends an ACK FIN packet using the same source and destination ports as in the RST packet. This is not forwarded to the laptop and I assume this is because the RST caused the nat table to drop that connection. Is this what should happen? If not, could someone explain how I should set up my firewall? Or is there something wrong between the windows machines?

I use the modules nf_conntrack_ftp and nf_nat_ftp to handle ftp & nat in my firewall.

Thanks!